# What do we call the receiver of a distribution

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that the person who is distributing something is called a distributor. what do we call the persons to whom the distributor is distributing.

Comment: You think they could be called recipients?

Comment: @user69786 I think 'recipient' can be used. But I hope there is a word that is more appropriate.

Comment: beneficiary would often be used for distributed financial payments.

Comment: I think "recipient" IS the word that's typically used in conjunction with "distributor".

Comment: Other words that come to mind are "end user" and "consumer".

Comment: I would say a "spark plug".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word that is generally used in the shipping industry to describe the person who receives a package is [**recipient**](http://thefreedictionary.com/recipient). [**Consignee**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consignee) can also be used; however, consignee is most commonly used for recipients of commodity shipments and is not a very commonly used word. [**Receiver**](http://thefreedictionary.com/receiver) is another option, but this similarly is not as broadly applicable as recipient, and generally applies specifically to the person in the role of receiving packages for a business when used in this context, and can be confused with its other meanings for a part used in radios and telephony or as a member of a team for various sports.

Answer (score -4):

Consider ***donee***. From [Merriam–Webster’s definition](//www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/donee):

> a recipient of a gift

Comment: the definition of 'Donee' in the link is - 'a person who receives a gift'. But distribution is not always a gift.